# How to Override Observable<T> for Testing's Sake?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, bdd, rx-swift

We're using Swift 2.x (latest) and want to BDD (unit test) our code. As an aside, we're using [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/) too. Our overridden method does not get called in our custom test stub. Our code:

```
protocol SomethingDeliverable {
    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<String>
}

extension SomethingDeliverable {
    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<String> {
        return create { observer in
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}
```

For testing's sake, we have this test code:

```
private class StubSomethingApi: SomethingDeliverable {

    var responseClosure: ((AnyObserver<String>) -> Void)?

    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<String> {
        return create { observer in
            if let responseClosure = self.responseClosure {
                responseClosure(observer)
            }
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of fetchSomething returning Observable<**String**>, we would like to return Observable<**T**> and have the StubSomethingAPI override it successfully for testing sakes. 
How can we do that?

Comment: It looks like a bug in Swift, I had experienced a same issue a week ago. Here is my code to demonstrate a bug http://swiftstub.com/399644727/

Comment: While exploring solutions in this, I was running into PATs (Protocols with Associated Types) that were not compiling - This talk by Alexis Gallagher - Protocols with Associated Types - helps me understand why: https://youtu.be/XWoNjiSPqI8

Comment: related: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/2015-December/000037.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
protocol SomethingDeliverable {
    associatedtype Element

    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<Element>
}

extension SomethingDeliverable {
    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<Element> {
        return create { observer in
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}

private class StubSomethingApi<T>: SomethingDeliverable {

    typealias Element = T

    var responseClosure: ((AnyObserver<T>) -> Void)?

    func fetchSomething(somethingId: String, associatedList: String) -> Observable<T> {
        return create { observer in
            if let responseClosure = self.responseClosure {
                responseClosure(observer)
            }
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }
    }
}
```